# Net::Ping Times Out

Tags: perl, ping

I have a very simple script to ping a host and find out the duration of the ping

```
use 5.010;

use Net::Ping;
my $p = Net::Ping->new();
my ($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping('google.com');
say $ret;
say $duration;
say $ip;
```

For some reason this keeps timing out (`$ret` returns `0` and `$duration` returns `5` seconds)

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The default protocol is TCP, which apparently Google doesn't respond to. It does respond to ICMP (although not all servers necessarily will): `my $p = Net::Ping->new("icmp");`

Comment: You are correct! If you submit it as answer i'll accept. Small aside, is it possible to do a ping if the url has the protocol as well (i.e. http://google.com)